# Primary key is not generating wiht my sequelize table

Tags: mysql, postgresql, escaping, sequelize.js

I am have a sequelize table that does not have a current primary key in it as ID. I currently am not sure why the id primary key is not rendering. I tried forcing the id to primary key and autoincrement.

Does anyone know how i can solve this issue.

this is what my current table looks like:

```
colabdesk=#  \d users;
                          Table "public.users"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id         | integer                  |           | not null | 
 username   | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 password   | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 email      | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 first_name | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 last_name  | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 DATE       | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "users_email_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
    "users_username_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (username)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "details" CONSTRAINT "details_userId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES users(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
    TABLE "profiles" CONSTRAINT "profiles_userId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES users(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL

colabdesk=#
```

this is what my sequlize table design looks like:

```
const seq = require('sequelize');
const { postgres } = require('../index');


const permissions = [['Admin', 'Staff', 'User']];


const User = postgres.define(
    "user",
    {
        username: {type: seq.STRING, unique: true, require: true, 
                validate: {isAlphanumeric: true, len:  [8,16]}
        },
        password: {type: seq.STRING, require: true,
                  validate: {len: [8, 18]}          
        },
        email: {type: seq.STRING, unique: true, require: true, 
               validate: {isEmail: true}
        },
        first_name: {type: seq.STRING, require: true,
                    validate: {isAlpha: true}
        },
        last_name: {type: seq.STRING, require: true,
                    validate: {isAlpha: true,}
        },
        permission: {type: seq.STRING, require: true, 
               validate: {isAlpha: true, isIn: permissions}
        },
        renter: {type: seq.BOOLEAN, require: true, defaultValue: 0,
                    validate: {isIn: [['0', '1']], isInt: true}
        },
        rentee: {type: seq.BOOLEAN, require: true, defaultValue: 0,
                    validate: {isIn: [['0', '1']], isInt: true}
        },
    },
    {
        createdAt:  seq.DATE,
        updatedAt:  seq.DATE,
    }
);


postgres.sync()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("User table is connected and synced")
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error syncing the User table: " + JSON.stringify(err))
    })


module.exports.User = User;
```

does anyone know how to solve this issue

**UPDATE**

this is what the request looks like:

```
{
    "username": "omarjandali",
    "password": "password",
    "email": "omar@admin.com",
    "first_name": "omar",
    "last_name": "jandali",
    "permission": "Admin",
    "renter": "1",
    "rentee": "0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the table was created as

```
create table users( id integer, ...) --which would not auto-increment 
as opposed to
create table users( id serial, ...)  --which would auto-increment.
```

If there is no data it might be just as easy to drop and recreate the table. You could also try

```
create sequence users_id_seq 
  increment 1
  minvalue 1
  maxvalue 99999999999999999
  start 1;

 alter table users alter column id set default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass);
```

If there is data in the table you will have to adjust the start value for the sequence.

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed to define the primary key in your model :

```
id: {
    type: seq.INTEGER, 
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
},
```

It should look like this :

```
const User = postgres.define(
  "user", {
    id: {
        type: seq.INTEGER, 
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    ... // <--- REST OF YOUR FIELDS
  }, {
    createdAt: seq.DATE,
    updatedAt: seq.DATE,
  }
);
```

Comment: i added the id field and I am still netting an error. do I need to pass an id when i make a post request to the database???